# Bug elixir gulp --production angularjs

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, gulp, laravel-elixir

I working with Laravel 5 and Angularjs, Laravel 5 uses Gulp for schedule asset's task and all work fine when use gulp's command, but when I use gulp --production's command and gulp minimize the Angularjs library, the console's chrome output:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
>   Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: e

Below my code:

gulpfile.js

First step, I copy all javascripts from bower folder to assets/js

```
    .copy(
        'resources/assets/bower_resources/angular/angular.js',
        'resources/assets/js/vendor/angular.js')

    .copy(
        'resources/assets/bower_resources/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js',
        'resources/assets/js/vendor/ui-bootstrap.js')
    .copy(
        'resources/assets/bower_resources/ng-busy/src/angular-busy.js',
        'resources/assets/js/vendor/angular-busy.js')
    .copy(
        'resources/assets/bower_resources/angular-ui-notification/dist/angular-ui-notification.js',
        'resources/assets/js/vendor/angular-ui-notification.js')
```

second step, I put together all libraries copied inside one file "libraries.js"

```
    .scripts(['vendor/angular.js',
        'vendor/ui-bootstrap.js',
        'vendor/angular-busy.js',
        'vendor/angular-ui-notification.js',
        'app.js'],'public/scripts/libraries.js')
```

My app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap','ngBusy','ui-notification']);


app.config(function ($interpolateProvider) {

  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');

});
```

I try different combination, but not working.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using inline annotation for dependency injection?
Here's a previous question that solves this problem
["Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr]" with angular after deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671962/uncaught-error-injectorunpr-with-angular-after-deployment)

Comment: Yes, I understand the answer, but I dont know how apply in my app.js file when I inject my library ngBusy, ui-bootstrap and ui-notification.