# Angular directive throws Error: [$injector:unpr]

Tags: angularjs, filter, directive

I am working on an project and need to modify some code to resolve an error
**directive:**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp').directive("myDirective", function ($filter) {
        return {
            // code
        };
    });
})();
```

This throws an error with the minified version only.
I am using angular 1.5.9

I think I need to define $filter somewhere.

Comment: I'd like to refer you to this: [Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Uncaught Error: \[$injector:unpr\]" with angular after deployment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671962/uncaught-error-injectorunpr-with-angular-after-deployment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have the app already defined somewhere.

You seem to have not injected $filter, try this instead:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('myApp').directive("myDirective", ["$filter", function ($filter) {
    return {
      // code
    };
  }]);
})();
```

Comment: He definitely did inject the $filter, but he didn't do it in a minify safe way.

Comment: You made my day.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using minified version of angular you need to inject the dependencies as a separate string array. Otherwise, dependency injector unable to identify which is which

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp')
      .directive("myDirective",myDirective);

    myDirective.$inject = ['$filter'];

    function myDirective($filter) {
        return {
            // code
        };
    }

})();
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.