# Angular Filter throws Error: [$injector:unpr]

Tags: angularjs, filter

I am working on an project and need to modify some code to resolve an error
Filter:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp').filter('filter1', ['$filter', firstFilter]);
    angular.module('myApp').filter('filter2', ['$filter', secondFilter]);

    function firstFilter($filter) {
        return function (element) {
            //code
        };
    }

    function secondFilter($filter) {
        return function (element) {
            //code
        };
    }
})();
```

This only appears to happen with the minified version.
It look a lot like [Angular directive throws Error: [$injector:unpr]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43114108/angular-directive-throws-error-injectorunpr) 
but the code is already injecting $filter.

What do i miss in this situation.

Comment: use `angular.module('myApp',[])` for first time.

Comment: You miss the fact that you need to post error message entirely. '[$injector:unpr]' alone says nothing on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I added your code in a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/flyTJMEjvlBK87fVcIl4?p=preview) (all console errors fixed) and I think you could be getting [`[$injector:nomod]`](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp) instead.

It occurs when you don't specify `angular.module('myApp', [])` the emtpy array describing dependencies. Check for that. To retrieve a reference to the same module for further configuration, you can call `angular.module` without the array argument.

Also, you have a typo in `firstFilter` function declaration which was misspelled as `firtstFilter`